# How to create all the possible combinations of elements in a list in python without disturbing the original sequence of the elements in it?

Tags: python

suppose we have a list in python 2.7.3

```
s=['a','b','a','a']
```

I want to calculate all possible combinations of this list elements without disturbing it's original sequence that is they will be as follows in this case:

```
['a','b','ab','ba','aa','abaa','aba','baa']
```

so 8 required combinations.

Comment: Your question seems to be not clear enough. What do you mean by "combination"? What do you mean by "without disturbing it's original sequence"? AFAIK sequences are quite well-behaved, and they wont argue with people. Do you mean that you want to preserve the `s` list without mutating it or that the *relative order* of the elements should be maintained? (in this second case your example is wrong because `'aaa'` *does* retain the order of the elements).

Comment: @Bakuriu: If the example given is indeed correct (with 8 results) then it would seem OP wants all possible *subsequences* of the original. (So not only the order must be preserved, but adjacency as well.) I agree that OP needs to clarify this.

Comment: @JohnY Maybe you are right, but the question is really unclear. In that case the solution would be pretty simple.

Comment: I am so sorry if it is unclear, well i mean to preserve the adjacency as well as the order of elements in the list in the all possible unique combinations. 'aaa' can't be the possible combination term in this case as there are no 3 consecutive a's in the original 's' list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your original question is a bit unclear, you should define combinations better, but here are some possible interpretations:

I use chain mainly to combine multiple generators, for most algorithms I have a generator per sequence length. For the given example there are sequence lengths 1,2,3,4. For each sequence length I solve a subproblem.

Mathematical combinations , treating each 'a' as a different value, this has 15 elements and duplicates. The subproblem is just applying the `combinations` function from `itertools`

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
s=['a','b','a','a']
list(chain(*(combinations(s,i) for i in range(1,1+len(s)))))
Out[3]: 
[('a',),
 ('b',),
 ('a',),
 ('a',),
 ('a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'a'),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b', 'a'),
 ('a', 'a', 'a'),
 ('b', 'a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b', 'a', 'a')]
```

The same as above, but no duplicates, this has 9 elements, it mainly also includes `'aaa'`.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
s=['a','b','a','a']
set(chain(*(combinations(s,i) for i in range(1,1+len(s)))))
Out[6]: 
set([('b',),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b', 'a'),
 ('a',),
 ('a', 'b', 'a', 'a'),
 ('b', 'a', 'a')])
```

Finally you might want to find all subsequences, this has 10 elements, but again duplicates. The subproblem can be solved by a smart `zip` trick. We provide to zip `N` arguments, with `N` being the sequence length of the given subproblem, we pass these by unpacking a list with `*`. Each argument is the original list, but starting from one position farther. So the first argument is `s[0:]`, the second `s[1]`, ... . Zip essentially combines these list by taking the first element of each argument and combining them in a tuple, then it takes the second element of each argument and combines those in a tuple and so on until the end of one of the lists is reached. So for example `zip(s[0:],s[1:])` will result in `[('a','b'),('b','a'),('a','a')]`, it stops after 3 tuples because `len(s[1:])==3`. As you can see this results in all subsequences of length 2.

```
from itertools import chain
s=['a','b','a','a']
list(chain(*(zip(*(s[i:] for i in range(n))) for n in range(1,1+len(s)))))
Out[4]: 
[('a',),
 ('b',),
 ('a',),
 ('a',),
 ('a', 'b'),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b', 'a'),
 ('b', 'a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b', 'a', 'a')]
```

Finally, the same as above but with unique elements, this result in the same output as your example:

```
from itertools import chain
s=['a','b','a','a']
set(chain(*(zip(*(s[i:] for i in range(n))) for n in range(1,1+len(s)))))
set([('a', 'b', 'a'),
     ('b', 'a'),
     ('a', 'b'),
     ('a', 'b', 'a', 'a'),
     ('b', 'a', 'a'),
     ('a', 'a'),
     ('b',),
     ('a',)])
```

I hope at least one of these is what you want. Also, going from the given outputs to the list of strings you provided is not much more than applying some joins.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.permutations`:

```
>>> res = set()
>>> for k in range(1, len(s)+1):
...     for comb in itertools.permutations(s, k):
...             res.add(''.join(comb))
... 
>>> sorted(res[1:])
['a','aa','aaa','aaab','aab','aaba','ab','aba','abaa','b','ba','baa','baaa']
```

Note that there are **13** possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s=['a','b','a','a']
>>> {''.join(s[i:j]) for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(i+1,len(s)+1)}
set(['a', 'aba', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'abaa', 'b', 'baa'])
```

This generates a set with the same values as your desired list.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [6]: s=['a','b','a','a']    
In [7]: from itertools import combinations

In [8]: print list(combinations(s, r=3))
[('a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a')]

In [9]: print list(''.join(c) for c in combinations(s, r=3))
['aba', 'aba', 'aaa', 'baa']

In [10]: print set(''.join(c) for c in combinations(s, r=3))
set(['aba', 'aaa', 'baa'])
```

I think, you need `itertools.combinations` and `itertools.chain`.

```
In [32]: comb_list = list(list(''.join(c) for c in combinations(s, r=i)) for i in range(1,4))

In [33]: print comb_list
[['a', 'b', 'a', 'a'], ['ab', 'aa', 'aa', 'ba', 'ba', 'aa'], ['aba', 'aba', 'aaa', 'baa']]

In [34]: print set(chain(*comb_list))
set(['a', 'aa', 'b', 'aaa', 'ba', 'aba', 'ab', 'baa'])

In [35]: print sorted(set(chain(*comb_list)))
['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'ab', 'aba', 'b', 'ba', 'baa']
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to generate all the unique sublists of the list.

Use [`itertools.islice?`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and a for-loop spanning all the possible lengths (1 ... length of the list). Add all the results to a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

The problem could also easily be expressed as two nested for-loops adding their results to a set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations`:

```
>>> res = set()
>>> for k in range(1, len(s)+1):
...     for comb in itertools.combinations(s, k):
...             res.add(''.join(comb))
... 
>>> sorted(res)
['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'ab', 'aba', 'abaa', 'b', 'ba', 'baa']
```

Note that there are **9** possible combinations. you forgot `aaa` in your example.

Comment: The `aaa` element is not in the requested set given that the elements order should be retained.

Comment: @claj I don't think so. The OP didn't specified it in its question. Also I don't see how `aaa` breaks the order of the elements.

Comment: It's not clearly stated but "without disturbing it's original sequence" does actually imply this. If you look at the example set it's also clear that there are no list breaking this rule. Not `aaa`and not `aab`for instance.

Comment: @claj "not disturbing its original sequence" to me it means it doesn't modify the original list.

Comment: Well, it's apparently up to @user2583372 to decide what was inteded then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but @claj got me right, aaa cant be in the possible answer because it breaks the adjacency rule of the elements in the original list.

Answer (score 0):

The following program suggests that there are **13** combinations:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def combinations(prefix, xs, theset):
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        x = xs[i]
        other = xs[:i] + xs[i+1:]
        newprefix = prefix + x
        if newprefix not in theset:
            theset.add(newprefix)
            combinations(newprefix, other, theset)


theset = set()
combinations('', 'abaa', theset)
print(theset)
```

Output:

```
{'a', 'aba', 'aa', 'ab', 'aaa', 'ba', 'aab', 'aaba', 'aaab', 'abaa', 'baa', 'baaa', 'b'}
```